# "dealloc" of UIView isn't called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, dealloc, retaincount

I have simple View controller

```
[.h]
@interface GLViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>{
    MGSplitViewController*          splitController;
}
-(void)setSplitter: (MGSplitViewController*)splitter;
@end

[.mm]
- (void)loadView
{ 
    GLView* glView = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] ];
    glView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    self.view = glView;
    [glView release];

}

- (void)setSplitter: (MGSplitViewController*)splitter
{
    splitController = splitter;
}
```

First, I init and push GLViewController into UINavigationController, which is defined as detailed view controller in MGSplitController. But when I pop my controller back, dealloc method of GLView class isn't called. The value of self.view.retainCount in dealloc method of GLViewController is 7, so, it's looks like something increases the reference counter of my view object by 7, but what can it be?

Comment: Wouldn't autorelease just quash all of those allocs?

Comment: I've modified my code and override release and retain functions in my GLView class.. see next post...

Comment: Sorry, I can't post answer to my own post. So, I just add NSlog to overrided retain and release methods of GLView class and in result I can see that object stays alive with retainCount==1 ...

Comment: The issue is resolved. The problem was outside of this view/controller and it has no relation to published code.